# VSTS History Queries

Tags: azure-devops

I'm looking for a way to query the VSTS history to return me all cards that have a Discussion entry within the last 2 days and have the word "public" in it.  Anyone have something for me?

It's easy enough to find the word "public", but I can't figure out how to relate that to the date of that Discussion entry date.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the work item History Queries, we **cannot exactly achieve** your requirements as no such a specific `date field` associated to the field `System.History`. However we can narrow down the scope, just try below query with the clauses:

Please note that below query will **get all work items** within the last 2 days which have discussions with the word "`public`" in it. That means if some work items have discussions which meets the conditions were **added 2 days ago** and someone changed other fields of the work items within the last 2 days, then these work items will also be included in the query result.

After that, you can open the specific work item and navigate to **History** tab to see the related discussions.

For the history queries please see [History & auditing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/track/history-and-auditing?view=vsts&tabs=browser) and [Query by date or current iteration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/track/query-by-date-or-current-iteration?view=vsts) for details.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input, but that doesn't achieve the goal as you noted.  I'd love to see additional capabilities around the Discussion section of a work item whereby each entry is treated as a unique object that one can gain access to.  Additionally, it would be great if add characteristics to each Discussion item (e.g., meta data, etc.).

Comment: @PaulB Unfortunately no such a feature for now, we cannot achieve the goal. You can submit a [user voice here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services) to suggest the feature. Besides, if you want to retrieve the Discussions which meet the conditions of a work item, then you can use the REST API to get work item history (revisions), see [Revisions - Get](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/revisions/get?view=vsts-rest-4.1) : `GET https://XXX.visualstudio.com/_apis/wit/workItems/108/revisions?$expand = all`, Just check the value of  `"System.History"`